# Assinging pointer to string variable fails

Tags: c++, pointers

```
match give_word(
    const vector< vector<string> > * source_words,
    const vector< vector<string> > * target_words, ...)
{
    string synonym1, synonym2;
    ...
    // choose synonyms (if available)
    synonym1=source_words[index][rand()%source_words[index].size()];
    synonym2=target_words[index][rand()%target_words[index].size()];
    ...
```

I've made a technical decision to pass all my vector-in-vector objects as pointers because I don't want them to be **copied** and passed to the function. It's because those vectors usually hold more than 1000 strings.

But what I don't understand is why I get the compile error at those two lines about the assignment sign (=)

```
synonym1=source_words[index][rand()%source_words[index].size()];
synonym2=target_words[index][rand()%target_words[index].size()];
```

It says this:
*No operator "=" matches these operands*

Comment: Why are you using pointers at all? I can't spot a rational reason why your code should need it.

Comment: Personally, I'd say if `nullptr` isn't a valid input you'd be better passing by const reference (which still avoids temporary copies).

Comment: Normally you would pass by reference to avoid a copy, preferably `const&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
synonym1 = source_words[index][rand() % source_words[index].size()];
synonym2 = target_words[index][rand() % target_words[index].size()];
```

would be a valid code if you used references, **which you should have**.

As for pointers, you'll need this:

```
synonym1 = (*source_words)[index][rand() % (*source_words)[index].size()];
synonym2 = (*target_words)[index][rand() % (*target_words)[index].size()];
```

That's called dereferencing (parentheses for proper operator associativity).

Without it, the pointer is canceled out by `[index]` (UB if `index != 0`), but luckily, it doesn't compile, because you end up with assigning `std::vector<std::string>` to `std::string`.

Similarly, with `source_words[index].size()`, you're getting the size of the `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` and not `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time there's a chance to use references over pointers, go ahead and do that.

Note that if at some point, you must use a pointer to a vector, you can always use the `at` function like

```
synonym1 = source_words->at(index)[rand() % source_words->at(index).size()];
synonym2 = target_words->at(index)[rand() % target_words->at(index).size()];
```

I know some people prefer to call like `myfunc(&vector)` (to somehow "make it obvious" that the function being called is going to modify the vector), so that's a way to work with pointers to vectors, or dereference the pointer as LogicStuff pointed out and then use the `[]` operator.

A very important fact though, is that the `at` function checks whenever the "index" is valid or not, while the `operator []` doesn't.